# Swing JTabbedPane ignores LookAndFeel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtabbedpane

I set the LookAndFeel:

```
try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
        | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

then I create a JTabbedPane but it is still not changed:

[image]

Comment: With that LookAndFeel everything else look slike windows 10 but JTabbedPane

Comment: Closed. Found my error.

Comment: *"Closed. Found my error."*  Then you should enter an answer revealing the solution, or delete the question.

Comment: Nothing special called the set look and feel method after creating the window.

Comment: *"Nothing special.."*  The point is, if it caused one app. to not work as expected, it has likely caused problems in other code for other people.  Given this is a Q&A site for solving such problems, it might have value to document this problem in the easiest way for other people to find the problem and solution.  Part of that is to have a question with at least one answer that identifies the source of the problem and the solution, as the accepted answer.  Otherwise this tends more towards noise, and should be deleted.